# How to change a css class property value for a specific mediaquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have the class

```
.foo {
  width: 30px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
   .foo {
     width: 20px;
   }
}
```

And I want to change the value of width from 20px to 15px with javascript for the mediaquery only.
When I do it, it changes the class for all resolution discounting the mediaquery in the CSS.

Comment: check `window.innerWidth` then change the width using `document.getElementByClassName("foo").style.width = "15px"`

Comment: can't you directly change in the CSS? why do you need to do it via javascript?

Comment: You could use a media query listener. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to workaround the issue. I used a listener on a matchMedia and everytime the browser crosses the limit, I run a JS routine to set the value in my elements (found by the css classname).
This way, it works like a media query, but the changing value can be anything.

```
                var w = 50; // Can change
                // media query event handler
                if (matchMedia) {
                    const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width:768px)");
                    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
                    WidthChange(mq);
                }

                function WidthChange(mq) {
                    if (mq.matches) {

                        // window width is less than 768px
                        changeFoo('foo', 20);


                    } else {

                        // window width is at least 768px

                        changeFoo('foo', w);

                    }
                }


               function changeFoo(aClass, value) {
                        var c = document.getElementsByClassName(aClass);
                        for(i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
                          c[i].style.width = value + 'vw';
                        }
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  document.querySelector('.foo').style.width = "15px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a separate class in CSS for this resolution and add this style to that tag when needed:

```
      if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
          document.querySelector('.foo').classList.Add("newClass"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change media query css, but you can make a css property, and set the property using javascript.

This way it only affects the css in the media query.

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('.foo');

setTimeout(() => {
  // This doesn't affect anything if the window width is above 768px
  foo.style.setProperty('--mobile-width', '15px');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: salmon;
  
  --mobile-width: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
   .foo {
     width: var(--mobile-width);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I thought about that but the value I need to set is not in a set of constants. It could be any integer. I'll explain what I did below.